# What .htaccess redirection has effect on Google bot?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, seo

I made one website xyz.com using php codeigniter framework. This website has modules, so modular extension is used. Now when this website is made live, every link shows index.php. So for this we can use .htaccess for modrewrite command. Till now my knowledge was cool enough. Now when my friend who has good knowledge of SEO saw my website links, he told me that your website will not come above(lower ranks) in google.

His reason is - your every request is pased through index.php. When google crawls your site, it will be redirected again to index.php which is main drawback. As he didnt have much knowledge about codeigniter, he told to fix this index.php issue as soon as possible. So I wanna know

IS HE GIVING A VALID REASON?? if yes...so how can I solve this problem.

Anything related to this issue from your side is also welcomed, as I may not have asked complete question.

Comment: If you use URL Look back you can use index.php as your script, but still have the document present from the URL given. No Mod Rewrite required. PHP is given the path to the document past your index.php as a query string so you can use that to find the correct context.

Comment: @mark tomlin : I cant get you. What you wanna say???

Comment: @aurelioDeRosa - http://www.onlineshop.local/index.php/mobiles    now i want that google should look for 'mobiles', not index.php/mobiles as 'mobile' is a keyword,  not 'index.php/mobiles' :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after your comment I can say that your friend is wrong. Google bot will never be redirected on the same page (index.php in your case). Of course is not very good that in each page url you have the "index.php" because you are losing important chars which otherwise can be used to put keywords.

Said that, your site will be indexed normally. Infact, many Joomla-based websites have the same behavior as you can see on this website ([parlaritaliano.it](http://www.parlaritaliano.it/index.php/it/persone)) which is very well indexed on Google.

Anyway, I advice you to replace (using **.htaccess**) the index.php in every of your urls because it is **better** from a SEO point of view. I repeat...better, it does not will cause any Google bot loop.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I didn't put index.php in every link. It is codeigniter's property that it gets automatically added to every link. Now .htaccess is a solution to it. But after searching lot, I found that if we use internal redirections in website, google will manage it, but htaccess redirection is external redirection and whenever google crawls it enter those modules/controllers from index.php because codeigniter didnt allow any execution to bypass index.php.But it may be the case, that google cache the actual url like: xyz.com/mobile after it crawls first time.wat u say?

Comment: @AakashSahai Of course you are not who are putting the index.php in the url (it's the framework behavior). Using .htaccess you are not bypassing the index.php, just it will not shown in the url (as it is implicit). Google can manage every kind of redirect. If you'll use the .htaccess, when Google bot will crawl your website, you'll have the url without index.php (as you want).

Comment: ok...thank u very much. Google and other search engines theories are not less than black hole. :)

Comment: I want to ask one thing more... for which keyword should I search (parlaritaliano.it) in google or other search engines?

Comment: Unfortunately for you it is an italian website (for the most). Anyway, it is a linguistic website so you can search for keywords like "Corpus CLIPS", "Corpus LIP", "parlato italiano" and so on.